# Why does this VHDL loop not terminate?

Tags: loops, vhdl

I am writing a VHDL program that bit shifts an 8-bit std_logic_vector called "a" to the right once per cycle of the loop, adding a '0' on the left side of the vector and incrementing the value of result by whatever was stored in the first index of a. It should eventually right shift until a is all zeros ("00000000") and the variable result stores the number of '1's that were in a. At this point it is supposed to break out of the loop.

But when I compile my code, it gives me an error saying, **"Error (10536): VHDL Loop Statement error at project4.vhd(75): loop must terminate within 10,000 iterations"**. However, it should terminate in only 8 loop iterations or less, so clearly something is wrong.

Here is the loop part of my code:

```
bit_shift_loop: loop
    if (a = "00000000") then 
        state_next <= S3; 
        exit bit_shift_loop; 
    else
        result <= result + ("00" & a(0)); -- Incrementing result by '0' or '1'
        done <= '0';
        state_next <= S2; 
        a <= '0' & a(7 downto 1); -- Bit shift right. 
    end if; 
end loop;
```

If anyone can see what I did wrong, please let me know. 
Thanks!

Comment: This is not a [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: because postponed assignment.

Comment: You are using a signal. Changes to a signal are not applied until the next delta cycle. So a <= '0' & a(7 downto 1); is never applied within the loop.

You can try using a variable in this case. As what you are writing doesn't seem to be writing synthesizable code at all.

If your target was to write something that would be synthesizable: don't use the infinite loop with exit statement. Probably even better to use a procedure or function.

And what were you thinking with the state assignments in the loop? Where is your clocked process?

Comment: You don't write programs in VHDL. HDL languages are for **designing hardware**.

Comment: @JHB - you should make that an answer. Staszek: VHDL is a systems simulation language; you *do* write programs in it. It may primarily be used for designing hardware, but that's not what it's "for".

Comment: @EML no, it's a comment, because there are still too many unknowns. Until the askers replies, I cannot form a proper answer.